# Formik & React Native: update parent value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, formik

I have a "virtual" field `inspection.images` that I need to update from a child component using `setFieldValue` but it is not updating. What I am doing wrong?

**parent-component.js**

```
...
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        inspection: {images:[]}
    }}
    onSubmit={values => {
        console.log('form values: ');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }}
    render={({values, isValid, handleSubmit, setFieldValue, errors}) => (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Walkthrough onChanged={this.onWalkThroughIndexChanged}>
                <InspectionForm navigation={this.props.navigation} values={values} setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                                mediaObjectsHandler={this.mediaObjectsHandler.bind(this)}/>
            </Walkthrough>
        </View>
    )}
/>
```

**child-component.js**

```
...
export class InspectionForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inspectionMedia: [],
            progress: 0,
        };
        props.setFieldValue('inspection.images', [...props.values.inspection.images, 'xxxx.png']);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> field should match the key of values you wish to update

Looks like you have to use `inspection` instead of `inspection.images`

Comment: You are right! I had to clone the object and change the image property and then call `this.props.setFieldValue('inspection', inspection);`

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped 